# Why thrift TBinaryProtocol read recv data more complex than just size + content

Tags: c++, thrift

Thrift version is 0.8. I'm implementing my own thrift transport layer in client with C++, protocol use Binary, my server is use frame transport and binary protocol, and is no problem for sure. And I get "No more data to read" exception in TTransport.h readAll function. I traced the call link, find in TBinaryProtocol.tcc

```
template <class Transport_>
uint32_t TBinaryProtocolT<Transport_>::readMessageBegin(std::string& name,
                                                        TMessageType& messageType,
                                                        int32_t& seqid) {
  uint32_t result = 0;
  int32_t sz;
  result += readI32(sz);      **//sz should be the whole return buf len without the first 4 bytes?**

  if (sz < 0) {
    // Check for correct version number
    int32_t version = sz & VERSION_MASK;
    if (version != VERSION_1) {
      throw TProtocolException(TProtocolException::BAD_VERSION, "Bad version identifier");
    }
    messageType = (TMessageType)(sz & 0x000000ff);
    result += readString(name);
    result += readI32(seqid);
  } else {
    if (this->strict_read_) {
      throw TProtocolException(TProtocolException::BAD_VERSION, "No version identifier... old protocol client in strict mode?");
    } else {
      // Handle pre-versioned input
      int8_t type;
      result += readStringBody(name, sz);
      result += readByte(type);         **//No more data to read in buf, so exception here**
      messageType = (TMessageType)type;
      result += readI32(seqid);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

So my quesiton is: in frame transport, the data struct, should ONLY be size + content(result, seqid, function name....), that's exactly what my server pack. Then my client read the first 4 bytes lenth, and use it to fetch the whole content, is there any other left to read now?

Here is my client code, I believe quite simple.the most import part I have emphasize that.

```
class CthriftCli
{
......
    TMemoryBuffer write_buf_;
    TMemoryBuffer read_buf_;

    enum CthriftConn::State state_;
    uint32_t frameSize_;
};


void CthriftCli::OnConn4SgAgent(const TcpConnectionPtr& conn)
{
    if(conn->connected() ){
        conn->setTcpNoDelay(true);
        wp_tcp_conn_ = boost::weak_ptr<muduo::net::TcpConnection>(conn);

        if(unlikely(!(sp_countdown_latch_4_conn_.get()))) {
            return 0;
        }

    sp_countdown_latch_4_conn_->countDown();

    }
}

void CthriftCli::OnMsg4SgAgent(const muduo::net::TcpConnectionPtr& conn,
                                 muduo::net::Buffer* buffer,
                                 muduo::Timestamp receiveTime)
{
    bool more = true;
  while (more)
  {
    if (state_ == CthriftConn::kExpectFrameSize)
    {

 if (buffer->readableBytes() >= 4)
      {
        frameSize_ = static_cast<uint32_t>(buffer->peekInt32());
        state_ = CthriftConn::kExpectFrame;
      }
      else
      {
        more = false;
      }
    }
    else if (state_ == CthriftConn::kExpectFrame)
    {
      if (buffer->readableBytes() >= frameSize_)
      {
        uint8_t* buf = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>((const_cast<char*>(buffer->peek())));

        read_buf_.resetBuffer(buf, sizeof(int32_t) + frameSize_, TMemoryBuffer::COPY); **// all the return buf, include first size bytes**

        if(unlikely(!(sp_countdown_latch_.get()))){
            return;
        }

        sp_countdown_latch_->countDown();

        buffer->retrieve(sizeof(int32_t) + frameSize_);
        state_ = CthriftConn::kExpectFrameSize;
      }
      else
      {
        more = false;
      }
    }
  }
}

uint32_t CthriftCli::read(uint8_t* buf, uint32_t len) {
    if (read_buf_.available_read() == 0) {

    if(unlikely(!(sp_countdown_latch_.get()))){
        return 0;
    }

    sp_countdown_latch_->wait();
  }

  return read_buf_.read(buf, len);
}

void CthriftCli::readEnd(void) {
  read_buf_.resetBuffer();
}


void CthriftCli::write(const uint8_t* buf, uint32_t len) {
  return write_buf_.write(buf, len);
}

uint32_t CthriftCli::writeEnd(void) 
{
    uint8_t* buf;
  uint32_t size;
  write_buf_.getBuffer(&buf, &size);

if(unlikely(!(sp_countdown_latch_4_conn_.get()))) {
    return 0;
}

sp_countdown_latch_4_conn_->wait();

TcpConnectionPtr sp_tcp_conn(wp_tcp_conn_.lock());

    if (sp_tcp_conn && sp_tcp_conn->connected()) {
      muduo::net::Buffer send_buf;
      send_buf.appendInt32(size);
      send_buf.append(buf, size);
      sp_tcp_conn->send(&send_buf);

      write_buf_.resetBuffer(true);
    } else {
#ifdef MUDUO_LOG
        MUDUO_LOG_ERROR << "conn error, NOT send";
#endif
    }

return size;
}
```

So please give me some hints about this?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have mixed concepts of 'transport' and 'protocol'.

Binary Protocol describes how data should be encoded (protocol layer).

Framed Transport describes how encoded data should be delivered (forwarded by message length) - transport layer.

Important part - Binary Protocol is not (and should not) be aware of any transport issues. So if you add frame size while encoding on transport level, you should also interpret incoming size before passing read bytes to Binary Protocol for decoding. You can (for example) use it to read all required bytes at once etc.

After quick looking trough you code: try reading 4 bytes of frame size instead of peeking it. Those bytes should not be visible outside transport layer.

Comment: Yes, you are right! The frame length is nonsense to protocol layer, after move 4 bytes ahead, and the left content is exactly protocol care about. Anyway, any suggestion to my transport layer implement? I just implement read readEnd write writeEnd four functions, enough?

Comment: never implemented new Thrift transport myself, but I think I'd add open close and isOpen to list of overloaded - just in case (at least isOpen). Good luck :)